# MS SQL Server management studio: how to add an external database to object explorer?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, linked-server

I would like to add an POSTGRESQL DB to object explorer in MS SQL Server Management Studio, how to do that?
The DB is linked in sys.servers and available for openquery queries

Comment: Have you tried browsing the PostgreSQL catalog via the Linked Servers node in SSMS object explorer? That will show tables and views but not other objects like functions, etc. If you need more capability, consider Azure Data Studio and add the PostgreSQL extension.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I need